# Computing $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} r^{4}\binom{n}{r}^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove the following identity:
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} r^{4}\binom{n}{r}^{2}=\frac{4^{n-2}n^{2}(n^{3}+n^{2}-3n-1)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{π}\Gamma(n)}.$$
I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096873/sum-k-0n-1k-binomnk2-and-sum-k-0n-k-binomnk2?r=SearchResults), but this is completely different. I know that
$$\binom{n}{r}^{2}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{n-r},$$
Also
$$\binom{n}{n-k}=\oint_{|{z}|\ =\ 1}\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{n+1-r}}\,\frac{\mathrm dz}{2πi},$$
I have no idea to started.

Comment: There is a similar question with exponent $2$ instead of $4$ on the $r$: [$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2{n\choose k}^2 = n^2{2n-2\choose n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299969/318073).

Comment: If $n\gt 1$, then your RHS is: $$ \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} r^{4}\binom{n}{r}^{2}=\frac{n^2 \left(n^3+n^2-3 n-1\right)}{4 n-6}  \binom{2 n-2}{n-1} $$

Answer (score 3):

In fact, an "explicit" formula for $\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^k\binom{n}{r}^2$ (assuming $n,k$ are nonegative integers with $k$ *fixed*, and under the agreement of $0^0=1$) can be obtained using [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition) of the second kind. We use the identity from the linked article, written as $$r^k=\sum_{s=0}^{k}{k\brace s}(r)_s=\sum_{s=0}^{k}s!{k\brace s}\binom{r}{s},$$ which gives $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^k\binom{n}{r}^2=\sum_{s=0}^{k}s!{k\brace s}\sum_{r=s}^{n}\binom{r}{s}\binom{n}{r}^2$$ (the lower limit of $r=\color{red}{s}$ justified by $\binom{r}{s}=0$ if $r<s$); now $\binom{r}{s}\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{s}\binom{n-s}{r-s}$ hence $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^k\binom{n}{r}^2=\sum_{s=0}^{k}s!{k\brace s}\binom{n}{s}\sum_{r=s}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-s}{r-s}.$$ And the inner sum is computed using [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity): it is $$\sum_{r=s}^{n}\binom{n}{n-r}\binom{n-s}{r-s}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-s}\binom{n-s}{r}\binom{n}{n-s-r}=\binom{2n-s}{n-s},$$ giving finally $$\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^k\binom{n}{r}^2=}\sum_{s=0}^{k}s!{k\brace s}\binom{n}{s}\binom{2n-s}{n-s}\color{blue}{=\sum_{s=0}^{\min\{k,n\}}{k\brace s}\frac{(2n-s)!}{(n-s)!^2}.}$$

For $k=4$ and $n>1$, taking out $\frac{(2n-4)!}{(n-1)!(n-2)!}$, we're left with $n^2(n^3+n^2-3n-1)$ as claimed.